# What's the name of that "ahh"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was watching an episode of Seinfeld today and quite humorously Elaine recalled a time that she 'had to' drop a class because of a guy who would go "ahh" after every sip of coffee.

Is there a name for that breathy "ahh" that's sort of like a relaxed sigh?

Comment: I think your *relaxed sigh* is pretty good already.

Comment: Really? There something humorous in an episode of *Seinfeld*?

Answer (score 2):

Without further context (I've never seen that TV show) I don't think there's a better word than the one you suggest: **"sigh"**. And it may be sigh of **relief**, **pleasure**, **exasperation**, **sorrow**, etc.

If the guy goes "ahh" after every sip of coffee, I presume it's **"a sigh of pleasure"**.